# What tree is on this picture?

Tags: identification

I now live in this house and have no idea what is this tree. It's on the front-yard and close to a retaining wall so I'd like to know what it will grow into
Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Where in the world do you live?

Comment: a closeup picture of a leaf would help too

Comment: Looks more shrub than tree, and evidence of previous aggressive pruning suggests that you can keep it that size with pruning shears, if you don't want it bigger.

Comment: @Jurp hi this is in California (not far from SF)

Comment: Leaves look a bit like citrus leaves to me.  Maybe a butchered lemon tree?